# UK Standard Visitor Visa refusal for lack of ties - how to reapply?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

I have twice been rejected for a UK tourist visa. I have completed BSc Information Technology in Organisation from University of Southampton United Kingdom in July 2014.

First time the tourist visa was rejected because of financial inadequacy. We overcame this issue and applied for tourist visa again.

Second time was rejected:

> I have considered the documentary evidence  you have now submitted to show that you have savings and that your parents support you in India. However, I note you have not demonstrated any employment status or continuing studies or commitments which require your presence in India which casts doubts whether you will leave UK at the end of the proposed trip.

They also mentioned that my sister can visit me instead:

> I appreciate that you wish to visit you sister however there is nothing insurmountable preventing her from visiting you in India. In view of the above, I am not satisfied that you plan to leave the UK at the end of your visit or that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor for a period not exceeding 6 months (Paragraph 41 (i)(ii) of HC 395 as amended).

I don't intend to stay in UK. I don't want to ruin my possibilities of touring around other countries in future. I just want to get rid of the refusal stain on my passport.

What's your suggestion?
Should I get employed in India or should I get involved in a masters program in India?
Which is the best option. What are the other options I should do as well and also how long should I wait to apply to get tourist visa so that I am clear of this blot so I can apply for a tourist visa to other countries without any worries in future?

Comment: As a small nitpick, it should read Paragraph 41 (i)(ii) and not Paragraph 4.

Comment: First, I don't believe it is a blot on you the way you seem to think it is. Second, think about your ties to India versus your ties to the UK. The UK Immigration knows you attended University in England and have made social and academic ties to that school and its alumni which you don't have in India. Next you have family in India, which is good, but you have a sister in the UK as well, so as far as family goes, India and UK are even, perhaps more towards the UK since it's your sister. With no job ties, UK immigration simply thinks you won't leave on time.

Comment: My sister's status in UK is of general Tier2 visa.My student Tier4 visa should have expired on November 2015 but as I didnt do my masters due to lack of funds and ended my Bachelors degree on July 2014 so I came back on August 2014 thinking that the even legally or orignally my visa would have expired on Nov 2014

Comment: With no job in India, there really is no reason for you to return to India, so that is why the UK won't give you the visa now. If you were to try for a Schengen visa, personally I think you may still have trouble, but not as much. Your next steps need to be to make ties back to India, either through more schooling or work, and perhaps an address and bank accounts/income in your own name.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am really grateful to you.Just last question, getting UK tourist visa refused twice, will it cause any trouble taking a tourist visa in other countries in future?

Comment: @Pramila, if you have a prior T4 which you aborted followed by two refusals plus a relative on a T2, you should be putting these questions directly to a licensed practitioner. You are what they call 'complex'; only a small number of people have the needed expertise and hence the internet is not likely to be of substantive help.

Answer (score 3):

Refusal is not a blot, it is just that the visa secretary did not find enough evidence to be sure that you will return back to India that is all. I have been to USA, Canada, UK and a few EU countries and some middle east and Bahamas people refused a visitor visa. I still go to other countries and if Bahamas doesnt like my money then its their loss.

When you say financial aspect is sorted you probably mean you put in some money into your account and applied again but that is not what the embassy people are looking for. They want continuous employment and money coming into your account on a regular basis and that is the reason they are after which makes them believe that you are making money and you have reasons to come back. Having money in your bank account is not a good reason for you to come back.

**What can you do?**

You can wait until you find a job and file your income tax returns and apply again.

When you apply for a visitors visa for another country it is an entirely different thing and has very little to do with the refusal stamps on the last page of your passport.